# Is there any obvious way to rewrite this code to work around a compiler bug triggering invalid C2244 error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc

The following is valid, standard-conforming code [from the GCC source code base](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/hash-table.h#L1147). It trips the Visual C++ compilers, triggering error C2244. [That is a compiler bug that I already reported, but it's unlikely to get solved soon](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Valid-C-code-doesnt-compile-causes-e/10513769). Too low of an impact they say. <sub>Now, I'd be rather miffed if my compiler product choked on a leading open-source compiler codebase, but that's just me.</sub>

Is there some workaround or a way to rewrite this to preserve the API while getting it past VS C++?

Getting the function body inside the class declaration works around the issue, but that's a bit of a stylistic nightmare and has about zero chance of upstreaming. So I was hoping for something less drastic.

Error:

> (17): error C2244: 'hash_table::traverse_noresize': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

Self-contained repro case below - also available [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:27,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:27,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:27,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:27),source:%27//+minimized+excerpt+from+gcc/hash_table.h%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+Descriptor%3E+class+hash_table%0A%7B%0A++typedef+typename+Descriptor::value_type+value_type%3B%0Apublic:%0A++template+%3Ctypename+Argument,%0A%09++++int+(*Callback)+(value_type+*slot,+Argument+argument)%3E%0A++void+traverse_noresize+()%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+Descriptor%3E%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+Argument,%0A%09+int+(*Callback)%0A%09+(typename+hash_table%3CDescriptor%3E::value_type+*slot,%0A%09+Argument+argument)%3E%0Avoid+hash_table%3CDescriptor%3E::traverse_noresize+()+%7B%7D%0A%0Astruct+D+%7B+typedef+int+value_type%3B+%7D%3B%0Aint+C(int+*slot,+D+arg)+%7B+return+%7B%7D%3B+%7D%0A%0Avoid+test()%0A%7B%0A++++hash_table%3CD%3E+ht%3B%0A++++ht.traverse_noresize%3CD,+C%3E()%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:54.06484424048516,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_35_x64,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27/std:c%2B%2Blatest%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x64+msvc+v19.35+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:45.935155759514856,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4). No compile flags needed, and AFAIK it trips all releases of VS 2022.

```
// minimized excerpt from gcc/hash_table.h

template <class Descriptor> class hash_table
{
  using value_type = typename Descriptor::value_type;
public:
  template <int (*Callback)(value_type *)> void traverse_noresize ();
};

template<class Descriptor>
template<int (*Callback) (typename hash_table<Descriptor>::value_type *)>
void hash_table<Descriptor>::traverse_noresize() {}
// Error C2244 in line above. Apparently, this definition doesn't match the declaration
// in the class body.

struct D { using value_type = int; };
int C(int *slot) { return {}; }

void test()
{
    hash_table<D> ht;
    ht.traverse_noresize<C>();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that MSVC is resolving the alias `hash_table<...>::value_type` early, and then failing to resolve it during member function (template) declaration matching.  Manually dealiasing at the definition appears to work:

```cpp
template<typename Descriptor>
template<typename Argument,
     int (*Callback)
     (typename Descriptor::value_type *slot,
//             ^~~~~~~~~~
     Argument argument)>
void hash_table<Descriptor>::traverse_noresize () {}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6M6Wevfhs).